# Wild match any characters for file name search as in Sublime Text editor

Tags: regex

In sublime text editor, after pressing ctrl-R a search panel will show up, then keying in some characters it will try to match part of the file name.

Say I entered 'ndjs', it will list following as matching candidates:

- nodejs.md
- node_runner.js
- debug.js

I was wondering how this is implemented? by using regex maybe? Would appreciate if anyone could point me to the right direction, thanks.

Comment: What did you want to match?

Comment: click on Incremental find on find menu from the menu bar to do a regex search.

Comment: this is known as fuzzy search

Comment: @AvinashRaj OP is asking how the Find in sublime text edit works, not how to regex something.

Comment: Yes, I'm curious about how Sublime Text provide that kind of fuzzy search, which is really handy. I thought that could be done via regex, but not really sure how to, any help? Thanks.

Comment: @hjpotter92 thanks a million for bringing up the word "fuzzy search", which leads me to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907825/how-to-implement-sublime-text-like-fuzzy-search

Answer (score 0):

@hjpotter92 thanks a million for bringing up the word "fuzzy search", which leads me to this: [How to implement sublime text like fuzzy search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907825/how-to-implement-sublime-text-like-fuzzy-search) –  Fluid